# Html form helper setTemplates for belongToMany selection

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3.6 and I've been adding some classes (`form-control form-control-sm`) to some input forms with `setTemplates` as the doc says. This way I've modified the tags `input` and `select` generated by `Form->control()` as follows

```
$this->Form->setTemplates([
  'inputContainer' => '<div class="input form-group {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
  'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>',
  'select' => '<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}} />']);

echo $this->Form->control('name'); // This is an input
echo $this->Form->control('client_email_id'); // This is a select
```

However, how can I modify the template (if possible) when a `belongsToMany` association is considered? Because the `Form->control()` helper will generate both tags `input` and `select` and it seems that only the `input` tags is modified. For example

```
echo $this->Form->control('projects._ids', ['options' => $projects]);
```

will generate

```
<div class="input form-group select">
 <label for="projects-ids">Projects</label>
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="projects[_ids]" value="">
 <select name="projects[_ids][]" multiple="multiple" id="projects-ids">...</select>
</div>
```

As you can see the `form-control form-control-sm` classes are only added to the `input` tag and not the `select` one. Does anyone know how can I make that happen?

I guess I could create a completely new template, but I want to know if it's possible using the `Form-control()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic `_ids` key causes a multi-select to be generated, which has its own template, namely [**`selectMultiple`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.6.12/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L157), which by default looks like:

```
<select name="{{name}}[]" multiple="multiple"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>
```

You'll have to modify that one too.

ps, you cannot use a self closing tag for a `select` control, this will mess up form generation as existing content (`{{content}}`) will not show up!

Comment: Thank you so much for sending the link to the source code and for spotting my 'select' mistake! It works perfect now :)